# Summation of $\log\left(\frac i2\right)$

Tags: summation, logarithms

Could someone just briefly explain why this summation is true?

> $$\sum_{i = 1}^n\log\left(\frac i2\right) = \frac n2(\log n - 1)$$

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Besides the probable typo, it's not true. You mean it as an approximation?

Comment: Let $n=1$ and you will see that the displayed formula is not true.

Comment: It is not true (obviously for $n=1$, the LHS is $-\log 2$ and the RHS is $-\frac{1}{2}$). However, the original of your question linked to some image that may have been scanned from a book/paper and seemed to have more context around it. Can you provide more information, please?

Comment: Where did you find it?

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log(i/2) = \log \prod_{i=1}^n (i/2) = \log \frac{n!}{2^n} = \log(n!) - n \log 2.$$

Stirling's approximation (applied somewhat crudely) gives $\log(n!) \approx n \log n - n$, so
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log(i/2) \approx n \log n - (1 + \log 2) n = n(\log n - (1+\log 2)).$$

---

If the original quantity is instead slightly different (the expression in your original screenshot is ambiguous), then
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \log i = \frac{1}{2} \log (n!) \approx \frac{1}{2} (n \log n - n) = \frac{n}{2} (\log n - 1).$$

Again, both of these are approximations (with an error term on the order of $\log n$), not equalities.